# Is it possible to define a Spark SQL expression as a named function?

Tags: function, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create/register a named function in Spark SQL whose body is defined as a Spark SQL expression. What I want is almost identical to a Spark UDF, but:

- the logic is simple enough that it can be expressed entirely as a Spark SQL function
- I don't want to use a UDF written in Scala or Python because that would incur ser/des overhead (especially so in Python, which I am using, but that shouldn't be relevant here since I am asking how to do this explicitly in Spark SQL)
- I don't want to write the function as a DataFrame transformation in Pyspark or Scala Spark because I want this code to be immediately portable between Spark environments (pluggable as a string into `spark.sql()`) regardless of whether running on Python or Scala
- I want the function to be callable as easily as `select my_function(x) from tbl` (identical to how a UDF named `my_function` would be called) since this is part of a simplified Spark interface for data scientists/analysts who are extensively familiar with SQL but not with other programming languages. The interface also exposes some project-specific UDFs we have written, but the analysts shouldn't have to care whether a function they're calling is a UDF or a spark expression under the hood. Effectively, I want a UDF's ease-of-callability without its performance overhead.

I have seen that certain built-in Spark functions accept anonymous lambda functions as arguments. For example [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) which accepts a list and a lambda function to apply to all elements in that function:

```
select 
  transform(
    array(2022, 1950, 1701), 
    y -> (y div 100) + 1
  ) as centuries

/*
creates:
+------------+
|   centuries|
+------------+
|[21, 20, 18]|
+------------+
*/
```

However, I cannot find out how to define a lambda function with a name inside the spark function registry using this lambda syntax.

I effectively want to do this, all in Spark SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION year_to_century AS y -> y div 100 + 1

/*
assuming there exists a table named year_tbl:
|year |
|_____|
|2022 |
|1950 |
|1701 |
*/

select year, year_to_century(year) as century from year_tbl
```

and the result would look like this:

```
year | century
_____|________
2022 |      21
1950 |      20
1701 |      18
```

But I don't know what the correct syntax is for the "`CREATE FUNCTION ...`" line. Does Spark SQL even allow for such a thing?